# Set function parameter, which itself contain other parameter

Tags: php, function, parameters

```
    function some ($html, $name) {
        return $html;
    }

    $outer_html = "<div>".$name."</div>";

    echo some($outer_html, "Jon");
```

I understood that I obtain `Notice: Undefined variable: name in`

But how set function parameter, which itself contain other parameter(s) ?

I want make this because, I need generate `$outer_html` out of function and after set this prepared html code to function.

Comment: Google for PHP templating, and read a bit about functions in PHP; but as you're not defining $name until after you've already used it, it doesn't exist when you set $outer_html.... even PHP can't predict the future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use [sprintf()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php)?

```
function some ($html, $name) {
    return sprintf($html, $name); 
}

echo some("<div>%s</div>", "Jon");
```

Output

```
<div>Jon</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the global keyword. Doc [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

You'll have :

```
function yourFunction() {
    global $yourVar;

    // ...
}

// $yourVar keep its value from yourFunction
```